# Oracle BI get data from sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, obiee

How can I show items in sharepoint lists in Oracle BI dashboards?

Bye

Answer (score 1):

I don't know oracle at all, but sharepoint provides industry-standart webservices< also sharepoint 2010 provides REST (Odata) webservices.

I'm sure Oracle supports webservices as datasources.